# How to denormalize JSON objects of objects?

Tags: python, arrays, json

Does anyone know any python package to de-normalize a JSON objects of objects? for example:

```
'{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,"2":16}},"2":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,' \
         '"2":16}}},"2":{"1":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,"2":16}},"2":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,' \
         '"2":16}}},"3":{"1":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,"2":16}},"2":{"1":{"1":16,"2":16},"2":{"1":16,' \
         '"2":16}}},"4":{"1":{"1":{"1":18,"2":18},"2":{"1":18,"2":18}},"2":{"1":{"1":18,"2":18},"2":{"1":18,' \
         '"2":18}}}},"2":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":18,"2":18},"2":{"1":18,"2":18}},"2":{"1":{"1":18,"2":18},' \
         '"2":{"1":18,"2":18}}},"2":{"1":{"1":{"1":23,"2":23},"2":{"1":23,"2":23}},"2":{"1":{"1":23,"2":23},' \
         '"2":{"1":23,"2":23}}},"3":{"1":{"1":{"1":26,"2":26},"2":{"1":26,"2":26}},"2":{"1":{"1":26,"2":26},' \
         '"2":{"1":26,"2":26}}},"4":{"1":{"1":{"1":26,"2":26},"2":{"1":26,"2":26}},"2":{"1":{"1":26,"2":26},' \
         '"2":{"1":26,"2":26}}}}} '
```

I would like to convert to raw format in terms of columns and rows (please see example above).

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [De-normalize json object into flat objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716636/de-normalize-json-object-into-flat-objects)